# Generating report using jdbc connection without entities via DynamicJasper

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

When creating the reports using *DynamicJasper 5.1.1* I am getting resultset from the data source, my pdf if empty after generation, not sure why my pdf is getting empty.

I took the code reference from [here](http://dynamicjasper.com/oldforum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=2835). Below is my code:

```
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.layout.ClassicLayoutManager;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicReport;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.FastReportBuilder;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DynamicJDBCReportHandler {

    static String username = "mnbfmwemf";
    static String password = "fwfwfwf";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DynamicJDBCReportHandler drh = new DynamicJDBCReportHandler();
        drh.getResultSet();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getResultSet() {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        JasperReport jreport;
        JasperPrint jprint;
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@wfwfwf:1521:fwefw", username, password);

            statement = connection.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM USER ORDER BY CREATE_DATE";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

            JRResultSetDataSource dataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs); // Here associate the resultSet with JasperReport
            FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
            DynamicReport report = drb.build();

            try {
                jreport = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(report, new ClassicLayoutManager(), new HashMap());
                jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, new HashMap<>(), dataSource);
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, "/report.pdf");
                rs.close();
            } catch (JRException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return  null;
    }
}
```

I don't want to create *.jrxm* file or *.jasper* file, I am sure someone should have done this if you could point me when I am doing wrong, much appreciated your help.

Comment: @Alexk can you help with this ?

Comment: What version of DynamicJasper are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.1.1

<groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
    <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @AlexK Do you think, something wrong with the version I am using?
I don't have .jrxm file or .jasper file do I need to create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is wrong?

You forgot to declare structure of report with help of [*FastReportBuilder*](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/FastReportBuilder.html). You created blank report with this line of code: `DynamicReport report = drb.build();`.

The right example:

```
public void buildReport() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionString(), user, password);
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query)) {

        JRResultSetDataSource dataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
        DynamicReport report = new FastReportBuilder().addColumn("Column1", "column_1", String.class.getName(), 120).setTitle("Sample report").build();

        JasperReport jasperReport = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(report, new ClassicLayoutManager(), new HashMap());
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<>(), dataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "./report.pdf");
    } catch (SQLException | JRException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("Failed to build report", e);
    }
}
```

I added column *Column1* and added title for report with this line of code:

```
DynamicReport report = new FastReportBuilder().addColumn("Column1", "column_1", String.class.getName(), 120).setTitle("Sample report").build();
```

---

#### More information:

[DynamicJasper Getting Started guide](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/)

[DynamicJasper tests](https://github.com/intive-FDV/DynamicJasper/tree/master/src/test/java/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test)

Comment: Got it, Thank you.

Comment: here I have to manually map the column names, is there a way to create columns dynamically?